# Calculate distance with LINQ, problem "could not be translated."

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a query to compare a given coordinate with coordinates from the database and return only those at a given distance.
Unfortunately, an error like the one below is displayed.
I used different libraries like GeoCoordniate, Coordinate, and it was always the same error.
What am I doing wrong? Can it be done in some other way?

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetSearched(
    [FromQuery] decimal? latitude,
    [FromQuery] decimal? longitude,
    [FromQuery] int? radius)
{
    var punkt = new Point((double)latitude, (double)longitude) { SRID = 4326 };
    var _term = from l in _context.Locations
        let punkt2 = new Point((double)l.Latitude, (double)l.Longitude) { SRID = 4326 }
        let dystans = punkt.Distance(punkt2)
        where dystans <= radius
        select l;
    return await _term.ToListAsync();
}
```

Error description:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Location>()
    .Where(l => (Nullable<double>)__punkt_1.Distance(__p_0) <= __p_2)' could not be translated.
```

Additional information: Translation of method 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry.Distance' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see [New feature topic: custom function mapping](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413) for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to `AsEnumerable`, `AsAsyncEnumerable`, `ToList`, or `ToListAsync`. See [Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038) for more information.

Comment: What kind of object is `_context.Locations`? Have you tried `from l in _context.Locations.AsEnumerable()`...?

Comment: That looks to be the issue. EF is failing to translate the linq where clause into SQL so it has to be told to filter client side per OP's additional info.

Comment: You have to write your query so that the call to `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry.Distance` happens client-side.

Comment: There's no way that EF can translate some arbitrary c# code to sql. Does your database implement a globe distance function? Then you might be able to map that method. If not, can you implement the calculation (or a rough approximation) in an `Expression` tree?

Comment: I am using the Microsoft Sql database. I have working sql code ->                                  Select * from Locations where geography::Point(52.091523, 21.001050, 4326).STBuffer(1).STIntersects(geog) = 1             but i dont know how to do this in linq.  I trying AsEnumerable() but still the same error.

Comment: @Enigmativity do you have working solution or could you explain how to do this ?

Comment: @Kamil - It's simple. Your error message tells you exactly what to do. `_context.Locations.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? Seems like you need to be using [NetTopologySuite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) to handle spatial data.